# Are auto-encoders usually over parameterized when pre-training for classification?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoders

In my auto-encoder, as I add depth, I notice that the reconstructed images are getting more and more pixelated. This makes sense because the auto-encoder is essentially acting as a compression algorithm and will get more compressed as we add more layers.

But in a classification problem, we don't necessarily care about the actual pixel values per se, but rather how the features interact in meaningful ways that describe the output. So we end up storing more information in the auto-encoder than is useful in our downstream application. We fix some of this by fine-tuning our network after pre-training, so perhaps the network replaces the unimportant pixel localization information with richer feature-interaction information, but that might not be guaranteed necessarily, or even needed, is that correct? So are networks usually over parameterized when pre-trained with auto-encoders?